# angular cli project indes.html

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I've generated angular(2) project and it generated the following index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FirstAngular</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see no "script" tag to include any JS bundler. I know this project use webpack but I don't see any reference to it in the index.html file.

After running the project everything works fine. I'll love if someone could tell me how this "magic" happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This index.html just acts as a template for webpack. Once you do `ng serve` or `ng build` the actual index.html will be generated and saved. If you look into the page source code in the browser, you will see the `script` tags are there.

Comment: Yeah I know that, my question is how is this happening? Where is the configuration for these behavior and so on, is this trick something that webpack is doing or angular CLI?